# Adding new Column based on Old Column in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as follows.

```
key     | value
inv_1_c | 5
inv_1_v | 8
inv_2_c | 9
```

I would like to add two columns to the dataframe Voltage and Current.

`Voltage` would be value if key ends with `"_v"` or 0 otherwise.

`Current` would be value if key ends with `"_c"` or 0 otherwise.

What would be the scala spark code for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `subString` function to get the last two characters and check if it contains `_v` or `_c` and add two new columns with `withColumn`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq(
  ("inv_1_c", "5"),
  ("inv_1_v", "8"),
  ("inv_2_c", "9")
).toDF("key", "value")

data.withColumn("temp", substring($"key", -2, 2))
    .withColumn("voltage", when($"temp" === "_v", $"value").otherwise(0))
    .withColumn("current", when($"temp" === "_c", $"value").otherwise(0))
    .drop("temp")
```

Output:

```
+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|key    |value|voltage|current|
+-------+-----+-------+-------+
|inv_1_c|5    |0      |5      |
|inv_1_v|8    |8      |0      |
|inv_2_c|9    |0      |9      |
+-------+-----+-------+-------+
```

Hope this helps!